# Fullcalendar headerToolbar button displays as two buttons

Tags: fullcalendar, ionic5, angular10, fullcalendar-5

I am testing fullcalendar/angular 5 in ionic 5 app and the header toolbar for views displays as two buttons:

[image]

This is my calendar options:

```
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    contentHeight: "auto",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'title',
      center: 'timeGridMes, timeGridDia',
      right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridDia',
    weekends: true,
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    allDaySlot:false,      
    initialDate: new Date(),
    firstDay: 1,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    locale: 'es',
    slotMinTime : "08:00:00",
    slotMaxTime : "23:00:00",
    navLinks: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    slotDuration: "00:15:00",
    slotLabelInterval: "00:15:00",
    eventTimeFormat: { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' },
    showNonCurrentDates: true,
    timeZone: 'local',
    weekNumbers: true,
    weekText: "S",
    buttonText: {
      today: 'Hoy'
    },
    views: {
      timeGridMes: {
        type: 'dayGridMonth',
        dayMaxEventRows: 4,
        buttonText: 'Mes',
        titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short'}
      },
      timeGridDia: {
        type: 'timeGridDay',
        buttonText: 'Día',
        titleFormat: { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }
      }
    },
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this)

  };
```

and this is html that it generates:

```
<div class="fc-toolbar-chunk">
    <div class="fc-button-group">
        <button class="fc-timeGridMes-button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button">Mes</button>
        <button class="fc--button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <button class="fc-timeGridDia-button fc-button fc-button-primary fc-button-active" type="button">Día</button>
</div>
```

Why generate the div with class = "fc-button-group" with two buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the commas in the string solves the problem...:

```
headerToolbar: {
  left: 'title',
  center: 'timeGridMes timeGridDia',
  right: 'prev next today'
},
```

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5821#issue-701022933

Comment: Nice!  Here I thought it was an unimplemented dropdown. You can also remove the whitespace after the comma and you get joined buttons (at least with bootstrap themeSystem).